# How do I know if Matlab is busy when using GUIs?

Tags: user-interface, matlab

I've created a small GUI to manipulate data and recently I decided to move the database to a MySQL server. I created a Java program to bring the data back and forth and I started to notice the delay when access servers abroad.

When you run scripts through the command window Matlab displays a "busy" text in the lower left corner but not when I'm running GUIs.

So how do I know if Matlab is busy when using GUIs?

Thanks in advance.

Edit: Quick example.

I run in the command window (or a script test.m)

```
for i = 1:100000
  a = i+i;
  disp(a);
end
```

The status bar says "Busy".

When I create a GUI, with the button "Click me" that executes the same exact script. The busy sign on the status bar does not appear.

Why is this and what can I do about it? I want to be able to see if my GUI is busy or not.

Comment: Rather than relying on the busy sign in the main IDE, could you not implement some sort of wait bar or print your own progress message to the command prompt. Both of these ideas are dicussed [here](http://blogs.mathworks.com/loren/2007/08/01/monitoring-progress-of-a-calculation/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to modify the status bar message of the main MATLAB window using the submission [**statusbar**](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/14773) from [Yair Altman](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/authors/27420) on the [MathWorks File Exchange](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/). He discusses how it works in [a post on his blog "Undocumented Matlab"](http://undocumentedmatlab.com/blog/setting-status-bar-text/).

With this utility, you should be able to put up a "Busy..." message even when MATLAB doesn't do it automatically. Your code for the "Click me" button callback would probably look something like this:

```
...
statusbar(0, 'Busy...');  %# Set the status message
test;                     %# Run your function/script
statusbar(0, '');         %# Clear the status message
...
```

Comment: Yes it is a neat little tool but when I said that I've created a small GUI I lied. For me, a novice, it is a pretty big GUI and adding this to all my callbacks (that need it) is to much of a hassle. It fixes the problem I had but is not the solution I was hoping for. I consider this problem solved. Thanks for your input.

Answer (score 4):

It says so in the status bar of the main window!

EDIT:
So the answer is no, right now there is no way to (easily) say if matlab is busy doing something other than a command line job.

Comment: This may be version dependent, but why do you need to know this, I mean I understand that it would be very nice but does it make anything dysfunction?

Comment: No just wanted to ask around if there was a simple way of plugging in to this "Busy" message in the main window. It takes a few seconds to retrieve "large" amounts of data, 10.000x10 matrices when the server is not at your doorstep. It would make the GUI more user friendly. The GUI is ignoring commands when busy so it is not a big deal at all. Thanks thou for your reply.

Comment: I for one, have far more annoying problems with MATLAB that I tend to automatically ignore these smaller problems. We use MATLAB on mac and  windows and linux machines and GUI shows up differently on each platform (its a busy UI with lots of small checkboxes and ...). On Lion it crashes all the time. There are annoying problems with parallel proc toolbox, with filter design tool box ... One day when I am the boss! I would move away from matlab to python + scipy ...

Comment: Blaming MATLAB for different looking GUIs on different platforms is not a legitimate complaint: that is an OS issue. If you posted your problems with the parallel and filter design toolboxes, you would perhaps get some useful solutions.

Comment: That is an OS issue is not a good excuse for a product that costs thousands of dollars. About the other issues I have been in touch with mathworks (sparingly) and I send them crash reports (more than one on days that I use matlab) but these are the kinda bugs that wont benefit us discussing them here, I should discuss then with matlab engineers (if they are around I'd be happy to talk to them more directly)

Answer (score 2):

You could add a static text on the GUI itself and set its text to 'Busy'/'Idle' before/after your calculations are done, if making the GUI more user-friendly is the concern.

Answer (score 2):

Probably what you are looking for:

Enter any arbritary code into the command line.

e.g. somthing like

asdfasdfasdfasdf

If the GUI routine is still running, then it will display busy, until the GUi function has ended.  Only then it can start to execute asdfasdfasdfasdf.

If the Gui is already finished, then it will execute asdfasdfasdfasdf instantaneously and display the according error message.

Earlier all Matlabs displayed also the busy message, when beeing executing a Gui-started function. Since 2012 this seems no longer to be the case.

Answer (score 0):

Add a static text box to your GUI. In your calculate icon callback, write this:

```
set(handle.text,'string','busy')
pause(0.1)
.
.
.
// Your code
.
.
.
pause(0.1)
set(handle.text,'string','done')
```

Answer (score 0):

[This thread](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/223637-is-it-possible-to-tell-when-matlab-is-busy-executing) over at MathWorks says it can be done using the [File Exchange entry CmdWinTool](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/32005-cmdwintool). If you download that file, you can use it to find out if MATLAB is busy with `CmdWinTool('isBusy')`. Note that CmdWinTool takes advantage of undocumented features in MATLAB's use of Java, so MathWorks is unlikely to support it.